# JSON acessando dois bancos de dados

Tags: php, mysql, json

Eu tenho duas queries:

```
SELECT Data, NomeDis, AlunID
FROM FaltaDupla
ORDER BY Data, NomeDis, AlunID

SELECT lNum FROM Aula
WHERE lDisciplina = 
AND lData =
```

Derivadas de uma função Delphi. A primeira é de um Banco Web e enquanto não terminar a segunda de um Banco Local é executada. Como posso gerar um JSON que se utilize das duas, sendo que pra isso terei que fazer uma conexão com o banco da web e outra conexão com o banco local?

Eu tentei dessa maneira, mas só consigo realizar o SELECT da parte Web:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
$opt = 
[
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
GLOBAL $pdo;

$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT Data, NomeDis, AlunID FROM {$pfx}FaltaDupla ORDER BY Data, NomeDis, AlunID")->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
echo json_encode($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisará criar uma outra conexão para a parte local (já que aparentemente você já fez a da web), como fez na variável `$pdo`.

Em seguida, com `PDO`, você cria uma nova query só que ao invés de usar `$pdo->query` você terá que usar a variável da conexão local (`$pdo` você usou para a conexo com o banco web). Digamos que a conexão local será `$pdo2`, você usará a query `$pdo2->query(SEU SELECT AQUI);`.

Digamos que você criou uma nova conexao para o local na variavel `$pdo2` e parao seu select, dessa conexão, usou a variável `$sql2`. Ficando assim:

```
$sql2 = $pdo2->query(SEU SELECT AQUI);
```

Para usar as duas em um único Json você faz o seguinte:

```
json_enconde(['web'=>$sql, 'local'=>$sql2]);
```

Aqui foi usado no parametro do `json_encode` um array que possui dois chaves-valores, "web" recebe todos os dados que vem do `select` da `query` de conexão web (que você definiu na variável `$sql`) e "local" recebe todos os dados que vem do `select` da `query` de conexão local (que eu defini como exemplo a variável `$sql2`).

Por fim, o seu código ficaria algo assim:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
$opt = 
[
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$pdo2 = new PDO(INFORMACOES DA CONEXAO LOCAL);

GLOBAL $pdo;
GLOBAL $pdo2;

$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT Data, NomeDis, AlunID FROM {$pfx}FaltaDupla ORDER BY Data, NomeDis, AlunID")->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql2 = $pdo2->query(SEU SELECT AQUI)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_enconde(['web'=>$sql, 'local'=>$sql2]);
```

Comment: fiz o que você falou só que agora na minha conexão local ele da esse erro: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'USUARIO' (using password: YES). Você sabe o porque?

Comment: Tem como você me mostrar um exemplo de como fazer um SELECT de um banco Web e enquanto não for o fim da query web ele faz uma query local (de um banco Local) e enquanto não for o fim dessa query local ele verifica se ela achou algo e joga em uma lista e monta o JSON dessa lista?

Comment: Este erro, no primeiro comentário, diz que o seu usuário e/ou senha para a conexão estão errados. Quanto ao segundo comentário, não entendi.